# create a dictionary with subdictionary from file

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I have a file in this format

```
Atomic Number = 1
    Atomic Symbol = H
    Mass Number = 1
    Relative Atomic Mass = 1.00782503223(9)
    Isotopic Composition = 0.999885(70)
    Standard Atomic Weight = [1.00784,1.00811]
    Notes = m
```

etc up to highest atomic numer in periodic system

I need to arrange the content of this file into  a  dictionary of dictionaries, where the keys of the main dictionary are formatted as symbolA (eg. H1,U235), and the keys of the subdictionaries are Z, A, m). Thus the dictionary will look like:

```
isotopes={'H1': {'Z': 1,'A': 1,'m': 1.00782503223},
          'D2': {'Z': 1,'A': 2,'m': 2.01410177812}
           ...}
```

Note that each nuclide element's name in the dictionary has to be written together with its mass number, for instance Hydrogen has to be written as H1, etc
I don't see how to proceed with this , I Have tried to start  with

```
filename='file1.txt'
isotopes={}
filename=open(filename,'r') #open file for reading
content=filename.readlines() #read file into variable content
filename.close()
for line in content:
    data=line.strip().split()  
    isotopes={'Z':0,'A':0,'m':0} #create subdictionary for each nuclide
    for key,value in isotope_data.items():
        isotope_data['Z']=i+1,
```

But I can't figure out how to advance.
Any hints?
When testing above code I just get

```
filename='file.txt'
isotopes={}
afile=open(filename,'r') #open file for reading
content=afile.readlines() #read file into variable content
#print('length of file array:',len(content())
afile.close()
print('length of file array:',len(content))
for line in content:
    data=line.strip().split()  
    isotope_data={'Z':0,'A':0,'m':0} #create subdictionary for each nuclide
    i=0
    for key,value in isotope_data.items():
        isotope_data['Z']=i+1,
        
        
print(isotope_data.items())
length of file array: 26800
dict_items([('Z', (1,)), ('A', 0), ('m', 0)])
```

Comment: Please provide an example input & output. For e.g what is Z, A & M etc..

Comment: The file content itself in its txt format is of the form   'Atomic Number = 1\n', 'Atomic Symbol = H\n', 'Mass Number = 1\n', 'Relative Atomic Mass = 1.00782503223(9)\n', 'Isotopic Composition = 0.999885(70)\n', 'Standard Atomic Weight = [1.00784,1.00811]\n', 'Notes = m\n', '\n', 'Atomic Number = 1\n', 'Atomic Symbol = D\n', 'Mass Number = 2\n', 'Relative Atomic Mass = 2.01410177812(12)\n', 'Isotopic Composition = 0.000115(70)\n', 'Standard Atomic Weight =  etc

Comment: filename='file.txt'
isotopes={}
afile=open(filename,'r') #open file for reading
content=afile.readlines() #read file into variable content
#print('length of file array:',len(content())
afile.close()
print('length of file array:',len(content))
for line in content:
    data=line.strip().split()  
    isotope_data={'Z':0,'A':0,'m':0} #create subdictionary for each nuclide
    i=0
    for key,value in isotope_data.items():
        isotope_data['Z']=i+1,
        
print(isotope_data.items())
length of file array: 26800
dict_items([('Z', (1,)), ('A', 0), ('m', 0)])